# XCTest: Check That a Callback is Not Called

Tags: swift, callback, xctest, xctestexpectation

I know how to wait for a callback with expectations in XCT. However, what about testing for the inverse?

Below is an example of a test that I have as part of my tests:

```
manager.state = .initialized
let exp = expectation(description: "expectation")
manager.login { state, error in
    exp.fulfill()
    XCTAssert(state == .initialized)
    XCTAssertNil(error)
}
waitForExpectations(timeout: 1)
```

In the next test I'm writing I would like a test to ensure that a callback is not called when my `manager` object's state is a specific value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done by setting `isInverted = true` on the `XCTestExpectation` object like so:

```
manager.state = .initialized
let exp = expectation(description: "inverted expectation")
exp.isInverted = true
manager.login { state, error in
    exp.fulfill()
}
waitForExpectations(timeout: 1)
```